# Cakephp 2.x Authentication Prefix admin and agent

Tags: cakephp, authentication, routes, prefix

Iam writing an application with cakephp where i will have admin and agents where they can login to the system. Admin will have different layout from the agents. I have already create the the users table where i added a role field (admin,agent) ,i added the prefixes in core.php

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin','agent'));
```

I managed to create the login and the logout for admin, but still  iam confused how i should proceed with the rest. For Example i dont understand how  beforeFilter()  and isAuthorized()  functions works. How i can check if user has access to that function or not. Also the redirections if a someone try to access this page domain.com/admin  to be redirected to admin/login page .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the beforeFilter() to control access to each action, the below example will only allow access to the view and index action - any other action will be blocked :

```
$this->Auth->allow('view', 'index');
```

if you want to allow access to all the actions in your controller , try this in your before filter:

```
$this->Auth->allow();
```

To control who has access to what you could use a simple function in your app controller like so:

```
protected function _isAuthorized($role_required) {
          if ($this->Auth->user('role') != $role_required) {
                 $this->Session->setFlash("your message here...");
                 $this->redirect("wherever you want the user to go to...");
            }
   }
```

In your controller action, eg. **admin_delete** on the first line you would do the following:

```
$this->_isAuthorized('admin');
```

Finally the redirect works like so:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
```

if you are redirecting within the same controller simply do the following:

```
$this->redirect('dashboard');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer i think its pretty much clear now. Isn't any better way to check if user has permission or not instead of checking the permission in every action?

Answer (score 0):

What i usually do is extend my App controller into an AdminAppController and SiteController , in the AdminAppController I have the following code in my beforeFilter:

```
$controller = strtolower($this->params["controller"]);
$action = strtolower($this->params["action"]);
$crole = $this->Auth->user("role");
$allowed = false;
$roles = array(

   "all"=>array("user#login","user#register","user#forgot"),
   "admin"=>array("pages#index","pages#view")
);

 if(in_array($controller."#".$action,$roles["all"])){

 $allowed = true;
}else{

   if(in_array($controller."#".$action,$roles[$crole])){
       $allowed = true;
     }



}


if($allowed==false){
$this->setFlash("Access denied message...");
$this->redirect("...");
}
```

Don't know if this is the best practice but it works just fine. I normally hate CakePHP's built in Authorization system.

Answer (score 0):

To check for allowance per role, I think it's best to use the Auth->allow([...]) in a per controller basis.

I find it best to check in Controller::beforeFilter() with a:

```
switch ($role) {
  case 'admin': 
    $this->Auth->allow(...); //Allow delete
    //notice no break; statement, so next case will execute too if admin
  case 'manager':
    $this->Auth->allow(...); //Allow edit
  case default: 
    $this->Auth->allow(...); //Allow index
}
```

While you can check in AppController, I don't want to remember to change two files when I edit just one.